# Swift toolchain location on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, command-line, installation

I'm looking into running Swift on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. However I want to be certain about where I should install the toolchain.

From [swift.org](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift):

> If you installed the Swift toolchain on Linux to a directory other than the system root, you will need to run the following command, using the actual path of your Swift installation...

Then from [Kitura's Setting Up](http://www.kitura.io/en/starter/settingup.html#ubuntu-linux) instructions:

> After extracting the .tar.gz file, update your PATH environment variable so that it includes the extracted tools:
>
> `$ export PATH=<path to uncompressed tar contents>/usr/bin:$PATH`

1. Where is the best place to install these type of things? In the past I would rely on `apt-get` or installation scripts provided by maintainers but this doesn't seem to be the case with Swift.
2. Are there any benefits or disadvantages to not installing it at the system root?

*Note: This question borders on "best practices", which I believe is frowned upon here. I'm sorry about that; I've googled around and this seems to be something that people know implicitly. However, I don't yet and need some guidance*

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  You should make that an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The versions of the software in your system root - in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share`, `/usr/lib`, etc. - are carefully coordinated by the maintainers of your distribution to handle all reasonable dependencies. The maintainers also keep the software up-to-date with bug fixes.

When you need to install software that isn't supplied by your distribution, it's best to install it in a separate directory, such as `/opt` (in your case, one possibility is `/opt/swift-3.1.1`). This will avoid overwriting existing installed software (in your case, `/usr/bin/lldb` and `/usr/lib/lldb`) with something that's possibly incompatible with other software. And it will make it easy to uninstall (just `rm -r /opt/swift-3.1.1` rather than having to get a list of files from the original tarball that are potentially strewn all over `/usr`).

There is some extra effort: you'll need to add `/opt/swift-3.1.1/usr/bin` to your `PATH`<sup>1</sup>. With some software, you'll need to add the directory containing dynamic library files to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The software's installation instructions typically explains what you need to do.

<sup>[1]</sup>An alternative to changing `PATH` is to add a symlink to each new executable, in a directory that's already in your PATH. [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) can help you do this.